# How do I rigorously show $f(z)$ is analytic if and only if $\overline{f(\bar{z})}$ is?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm doing a bit of self study, but I'm uncomfortable with a certain idea. I want to show that $f(z)$ is analytic if and only if $\overline{f(\bar{z})}$ is analytic, and by analytic I mean differentiable at each point. Here $f$ is a complex valued function.

What I do is write $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, where $u$ and $v$ are real functions of two variables. Then $\overline{f(\bar{z})}=u(x,-y)-iv(x,-y)$.

These two forms look very similar, in the sense the one function being differentiable should immediately imply the other is differentiable, since the only thing really changing might be a $-$ sign popping out due to the chain rule.

How can I more rigorously express that $f(z)$ is analytic iff $\overline{f(\bar{z})}$ using this? Many thanks.

Comment: Analytic is equivalent to Cauchy Riemann equations + C^1. So verify the Cauchy-Riemann equations using a simple application of chain rule.

Comment: How would you show this *nonrigurously*?

Comment: Problem given by Ahlfors in Complex Analysis Page 28

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Define $g(z)=\overline{f(\overline z)}$.  Then note that $f(z)=\overline{g(\overline z)}$, so there is symmetry allowing only one implication to be shown directly.  Suppose that $f$ is analytic.  Then for all $z$,

$$\begin{align*}g'(z)&=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{g(z+h)-g(z)}{h}\\
&=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\overline{f(\overline{z+h})}-\overline{f(\overline z)}}{h}\\
&=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\overline{\left( \frac{f(\overline z+\overline h)-f(\overline z)}{\overline h} \right)    }\\
&=\overline{\left( \lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(\overline z+\overline h)-f(\overline z)}{\overline h} \right)    }\\
&=\overline{f'(\overline z)}.
\end{align*}$$

That is, $g$ is differentiable, with $g'(z)=\overline{f'(\overline z)}$.

---

Alternatively, as other answers have indicated, you could check that the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) hold for $g$ if they hold for $f$, with $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ and $g(x+iy)=u(x,-y)+i(-v(x,-y))$ as you indicated.

---

Another perhaps more conceptual way to think of this is that complex analytic maps are [conformal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map) (where their derivatives are nonzero), preserving orientation and angles.  Complex conjugation preserves angles but reverses orientation.  Reversing orientation twice gets you back where you started, so the result is that $g$ is conformal.  (I have given an idea here rather than anything close to a rigorous proof.)

---

Another approach is to look at power series expansions.  If $f$ has power series expansion in a neighborhood of $\overline{c}$, $\displaystyle{f(z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k(z-\overline c)^k}$, then in a neighborhood of $c$, $g$ has the power series expansion $\displaystyle{g(z)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\overline{a_k}(z-c)^k}$.  That is, you just conjugate the coefficients and conjugate the base point for the expansion.  This shows that $g$ is analytic if $f$ is.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I was thinking about doing it the first way you show, but doesn't it require some justification to move the limit inside the complex conjugation? I wasn't sure how to provide it, so I shied away.

Comment: @Dedede: Moving a limit inside conjugation is justified by continuity, and in fact conjugation preserves distances.  Suppose that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0}F(h)=a$.  If you want a rigorous definition, this means that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $0<|h|<\delta$ implies $|F(h)-a|<\varepsilon$.  But then $0<|h|<\delta$ implies $|\overline{F(h)}-\overline{a}|=|F(h)-a|<\varepsilon$, from which it follows that $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \overline{F(h)}=\overline a$.  This only uses the fact that $|\overline z|=|z|$ for all $z$.

Comment: @Dedede: By the way, this is the same reason conjugating a power series term-by-term is justified. (Also, where I wrote "only uses" in my last comment wasn't quite right, because it also uses $\overline{z-w}=\overline z-\overline{w}$ for all $w$ and $z$.)

Comment: Thanks Jonas, this was very comprehensive.

Answer (score 27):

Use the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Say $\overline{f(\bar{z})}=\alpha(x,y)+i\beta(x,y)$, so that you have

$$\alpha(x,y)=u(x,-y);$$
$$\beta(x,y)=-v(x,-y).$$

Thus

$$\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x}=u_x(x,-y),\qquad \frac{\partial\beta}{\partial y}=(-1)\cdot(-v_y(x,-y))=v_y(x,-y);$$

$$\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial y}=(-1)\cdot u_y(x,-y),\qquad\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial x}= -v_x(x,-y).$$

Show that if one or the other of $\alpha,\beta$ and $u,v$ satisfies CR, so does the other pair.

Comment: Thanks anon. So assuming it holds for $u$ and $v$, I can say: $$\frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial x}=u_x(x,-y)=v_y(x,-y)= \frac{\partial\beta}{\partial y}$$ and $$ \frac{\partial\alpha}{\partial y}=-u_y(x,-y)=v_x(x,-y)= -\frac{\partial\beta}{\partial x}$$? And the converse essentially follows from the same equalities?

Comment: @Dedede: Almost; $\displaystyle \frac{\partial\beta}{\partial x}=\color{Red}- v_x(x,-y)$. After that fix the converse follows from the equalities.

Comment: Very well explained! Thank you!

Comment: @Bman72 but doesn't the C-R equations say that u need $u_y=-v_x$, not $u_y=v_x$? Why is there e negative on both sides when computing $u_y,v_x$?

Comment: @anon for the C-R equations, doesn't $u_y$ have to equal $-v_x$?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Answer (score 4):

Let $K$ be a Hausdorff topological field, let $f$ be a $K$-valued function defined on an open subset $U$ of $K$, and let $a$ be a point of $U$.

Say that $f$ is *differentiable* at $a$ if there is a function $g$ from $U$ to $K$ which is continuous at $a$ and satisfies 
$$
f(z)=f(a)+(z-a)\ g(z)
$$
for all $z$ in $U$. In this case, we write $f'(a):=g(a)$. (One easily checks that this makes sense.)

Assume that this condition holds, and that $\phi$ is an automorphism of $K$ viewed as a topological field.

Then $z\mapsto\phi(f(\phi^{-1}(z))$ is differentiable at $\phi(a)$, and we have 
$$
(\phi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1})'(\phi(a))=\phi(f'(a)).
$$
The proof is straightforward.

**EDIT.** Here is the proof. By assumption we have 
$$
f(z)=f(a)+(z-a)\ g(z)\ \ \forall\ z\in U,\quad f'(a)=g(a).
$$
Put 
$$
\widetilde f:=\phi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1},\quad \widetilde g:=\phi\circ g\circ\phi^{-1},\quad 
\widetilde a:=\phi(a),\quad \widetilde z:=\phi(z),\quad \widetilde U:=\phi(U).
$$ 
This yields
$$
\widetilde f(\widetilde z\,)=\widetilde f(\widetilde a\,)+(\widetilde z-\widetilde a\,)\ \widetilde g(\widetilde z\,)\ \ \forall\ \widetilde z\in\widetilde U,\quad\left(\widetilde f\ \right)'(\widetilde a\,)=\widetilde g(\widetilde a\,)=\phi(f'(a)).
$$
This fashion of stating the definition of differentiability is due Carathéodory. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58388/660).

Answer (score 1):

Another way: Morera's Theorem.  Of course you have to figure our how two convert between integral $dz$ and integral $d\overline{z}$.

Comment: Can you elaborate the this hint a little? (I am not so mature with analysis beyond epsilon-delta job)